# X editable django and jquery yu

Tags: ajax, django, jquery-ui

I'm trying to update a field using X Editable but I do not make it till the end.

Here is my code:

```
#views.py

def update_task(request, task_id):
if request.is_ajax():
    task = request.GET.get('task')
    updated_task = Task.objects.get(pk=task_id)
    updated_task.task = task
    updated_task.save()
        return HttpResponse('true')
else:
    return HttpResponse('not ajax')

#urls.py

url(r'^update_task/(?P<task_id>\d+)/$', 'todo.views.update_task', name='update_task'),

#html file
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#task").editable({
        type: 'text',
        pk: 144,
        url: '/update_task/144/',
        title: 'Enter task',
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I'm trying to update it console gives me:

> link/update_task/144 404 (Not found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see that you have a url defined to capture the `task_id`

I think you need to either put the `task_id` in the parameter, so something like `url + '?task_id=144`.

If you do this, you need to change your javascript line to look like this:

```
url: '/update_task/' + '?task_id=144',
```

or, you need to leave it as is, and add a line to your url conf to capture the parameter:

```
url(r'^update_task/(?P<task_id>\d+)/$', 'todo.views.update_task', name='update_task'),
```

and then in your views:

```
def update_task(request, task_id=None):#if task_id is optional, set it to =None or something
    if request.is_ajax():
        do stuff here with task_id
```

also, you will need to take out the `task_id = request.GET.get('task_id')`

because task_id is not in the GET body.

Comment: it updates on the page but in database not :(. I chose to modify the url. Any idea why? I updated the code.